# Is there any way to batch convert FSCK rec files?

Tags: usb, fsck

I plugged in my USB this morning and went to grab a few files, but realized the folder was empty. Checked the usb drive properties and it said only 6,4 MB unused, while the folder had nothing in it, tried Ctrl + H, tried ls -a, none worked.

With Gparted I managed to run a Check and it made them all reappear, but as a bunch of FSCK****.rec files, which most of them still work, but quite a few I have no idea what they were before. Bunch of .js files turned into "C Source Code" which I think corrupted them, audio and video files seem ok, but thats as much as I could check.

I did make an image of the USB drive before running the check, so if there is other tools I could use to recover or fix those, it'd be much appreciated.